# Bing Ads API: endpoint configuration in .config

Tags: .net, wcf, bing-ads-api

I've got an ASP.Net MVC (Framework version 4.6.2) site where I'm trying to integrate daily expense totals from our Bing Ads campaign through the API.

I've added the package `Microsoft.BingAds.SDK` through Nuget and written some code against its classes that compiles, so I figured I could fire it up and see what happens.

What happens is this:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'Microsoft.BingAds.V11.Reporting.IReportingService' in the
>   ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no
>   configuration file was found for your application, or because no
>   endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client
>   element.

The error happens in the constructor of the ReportingServiceClient():

```
var client = new ReportingServiceClient();
```

I'm not sure how to proceed. There is indeed no endpoint configured in my .config file. I would have expected Nuget to add necessary config, but there's nothing. I have no idea why it didn't, or what I'm supposed to be adding to my .config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have more details e.g., code snippet where you create and use the service client? Are you using A) ReportingServiceManager or B) ServiceClient?

```
AuthorizationData authorizationData = new AuthorizationData
{
    // By this point OAuthWebAuthCodeGrant already has 
    // access and refresh tokens
    Authentication = OAuthWebAuthCodeGrant,
    DeveloperToken = "DeveloperTokenGoesHere"
};

// Option A: ReportingServiceManager
ReportingServiceManager reportingServiceManager = new ReportingServiceManager(authorizationData);

// Option B: ServiceClient<IReportingService>
ServiceClient<IReportingService> service = new ServiceClient<IReportingService>(authorizationData);
```

Here is an [example web solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingads/guides/walkthrough-web-application-csharp) from the API Docs. I suggest that you also review [this example from GitHub](https://github.com/BingAds/BingAds-dotNet-SDK/blob/master/examples/BingAdsExamples/BingAdsExamplesLibrary/v12/ReportRequests.cs#L52) that uses [ReportingServiceManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingads/guides/sdk-reporting-service-manager).

Also note that I installed System.ServiceModel.Primitives 4.4.1, System.ServiceModel.Http 4.4.1, and System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationManager 4.4.1 (ran into issues several weeks ago with some other versions) as [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingads/guides/get-started-csharp#package-manager).

I hope this helps!

Comment: I get it at the constructor of the ReportingServiceClient. 
Did your projects get the proper endpoint in the .config file?

Comment: Turns out my mistake was creating a ReportingServiceClient at all. 

It sounds like a useful class, but all it does is complain about EndPoints. I think that class should probably have been internal rather than public.